# Appwrite OAuth google in Flutter web application

Tags: google-oauth, appwrite

```
FlutterLogin(
     loginProviders: [ LoginProvider(
     button: Buttons.google,
     callback: () async { try { final d = await account.createOAuth2Session(provider: 'google');
    return null;
                } on Exception catch (e) {
                  return 'Error google';
                }
              })
        ],........
```

OAuth 2.0 client in google console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiejS.png)

in app write
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZLgv.png)

An error occurred while attempting to log in -

> Error: Invalid argument (callbackUrlScheme): must be a valid URL
> scheme: "appwrite-callback-AllMarket"

In documentation Appwrite - For web in order to capture the OAuth2 callback URL and send it to the application using JavaScript postMessage(), you need to create an html file inside ./web folder of your Flutter project. For example auth.html with the following content.

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Authentication complete</title>
<p>Authentication is complete. If this does not happen automatically, please
close the window.
<script>
  window.opener.postMessage({
    'flutter-web-auth-2': window.location.href
  }, window.location.origin);
  window.close();
</script>
```

<!-- end snippet -->

Created this file, put it in the root directory of the site, but did not understand how to use it. Please help deal with the error.

Answer (score 0):

For a Flutter web application, you'll need to pass a success URL to `createOAuth2Session()`. The success URL should be the URL to that HTML you created. Assuming you put it in the `web` folder of your flutter project, the success URL would be `https://[hostname of your flutter app]/auth.html`.

For more information, see these examples:

1. [auth.html](https://github.com/appwrite/playground-for-flutter/blob/master/web/auth.html)
2. [createOAuth2Session()](https://github.com/appwrite/playground-for-flutter/blob/ceea7c3b491506d4c1f7c8da5149153824092eec/lib/main.dart#L290)